# Dynamics CRM 2011 ribbon on custom html form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

I have a custom asp.net website wich is called from Dynamics CRM 2011 and I need it to look exactly like CRM 2011 standart window.

I managed to create almost all custom webcontrols which look like they are from Dynamics CRM 2011 except one, the Ribbon.

I triedto take out and clean the HTML from CRM but results aren't very good so far.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what else you can do Grigory - copying the existing HTML would only ever have been a head start anyway I would imagine. These are not especially complex looking objects (some divs with background images and rollover effect). Can't you just hand craft it?

There's no way to reuse the native controls and I'm not aware of anything commercial that you can go out and just buy.